# Flutter table: how to refresh one table row only?

Tags: flutter

```
Table
   TableRow1
     TableCell
     TableCell
     WidgetA
   TableRow2
   TableRow3
```

TableRow is not a StatefulWidget. How to tell flutter to refresh/rebuild one row only (e.g., 1st row)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ValueNotifier` for each cell. I am assuming you like to update your `WidgetA`.

```dart
class TableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<int> counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(),
      children: <TableRow>[
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: counter,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Text(
                  '$value',
                );
              },
            ),
            Container(
              height: 32,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: () => counter.value = counter.value + 1, child: const Text("Increment")),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but an entire row needs to be rebuilt in general. For example, a table has 30 columns, of which 20 columns has been changed and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: I might go with state-management solution, also you can create custom class by extending TableRow.